# networking on android emulator on linux

Tags: linux, networking, fedora, android-studio

How can I get network to work on android studio emulator on Linux (Fedora 29), I've read a lot but not anything helpful and simple it is all mess. I did  `telnet localhost 5554`  and it looks ok 
`Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Android Console: Authentication required
Android Console: type 'auth <auth_token>' to authenticate
Android Console: you can find your <auth_token> in 
'/home/roberto/.emulator_console_auth_token'
OK`

but it is not working thanks, try few sites on chrome but no network

Comment: have you looked in the file `/home/roberto/.emulator_console_auth_token` (on your host machine) and done the `auth <auth_token>` command as suggested? It looks a lot like networking is indeed working, you just need to authenticate.

Comment: so I typed `auth <token>` in the same console I got OK but it still won't work